# CentOS server with Cpanel - Deploying Flask Application With Mod_Wsgi

Tags: apache, python-3.x, flask, cpanel

I trying to deploy Flask application on VPS(Cenos) already installed WHM/Cpanel.
i have installed in it python 3.5 and trying to install mod_wsgi and it give me error:
*Error: Package: mod_wsgi-3.2-7.el6.x86_64 (base)
Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest*

Please guide me anyone How to properly deploy a flask application on a VPS(Centos) with CPANEL with multiple Domains.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How old is your CentOS? Version 3.2 of mod_wsgi is ancient and should not be used. You might want to consider a VPS provider which has more up to date operating system and software.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the centos version i have is :  centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64

Comment: Well the mod_wsgi is ancient for some reason and would only be for Python 2.X (possibly only 2.6) anyway and not Python 3.5. You would need to install mod_wsgi yourself from source code.

Comment: MR. @GrahamDumpleton . I really Appreciate your reply on my post. Please can you give me reference from where i can follow the procedure to install it from source with python 3. Thanks :)

Comment: It isn't that simple as CPanel managed sites tend to be locked down and don't allow you to do much. So is very hard for me to direct you as to how to do it. Try though at least reading through docs at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi and on main mod_wsgi site.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i have managed to download the source and install from it but whiling compiling it i receive an error:-->  **checking Apache version... ./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2765: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2766: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 2769: /: is a directory

./configure: line 2964: apxs: command not found**.  -- I have tried to install httpd-devel in centos but it says :  **No package httpd-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do **

Comment: What is the httpd package name that is currently installed? What is the ``httpd`` version, find ``httpd`` and run ``httpd -V``. CPanel may not actually be using OS ``httpd`` packages but could be using its own Apache install. Do you get any result for ``find / -name apxs``?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton below are results for httpd -V: Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (cPanel)
Server built:   Nov  8 2016 16:57:01
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     worker
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP  --- More

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton tried to run find / -name apxs command below results : root@iie [~/mod_wsgi-4.4.21]# find / -name apxs
find: `/proc/13636': No such file or directory

Comment: Where is ``httpd`` itself installed?

Comment: Mr. @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for your efforts. please guide me how to check where httpd is installed, and i have executed this command "root@iie # which apxs" , return was = "/usr/bin/apxs" . also i have tried this comamnd "root@iie # whereis apxs" , return was = "apxs: /usr/bin/apxs /usr/share/man/man1/apxs.1.gz"

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton i am following these commands to install mod_wsgi: >  echo 'Now, install mod_wsgi...' 
> wget -q "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.4.21.tar.gz"
> tar -xzf '4.4.21.tar.gz'
> cd ./mod_wsgi-4.4.21
> ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
> make
> make install

Comment: Why are you using 4.4.21. The latest version is 4.5.10.

Comment: How is it you now have ``apxs`` installed now where as you didn't before? Did you manage to install ``https-devel`` package after all?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton when i am trying this command= " yum install httpd-devel" . return = "> No package httpd-devel available.
> Error: Nothing to do
"  Mr GrahamDumpleton can you say me how to check if it is already installed or not ?

Comment: You said ``which apxs`` returns ``/usr/bin/apxs`` which suggests the program does exist. What happens when you run ``apxs -q APR_CONFIG``? If it gives a path name, does the file at that location exist?